# A function to get Custom Field in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity

I am writing a custom function to populate an email field in gravity forms in wordpress. I would like to call my custom field-"app_email-address" that is present in each post to the email field.

If is use the below function, the email field is populated with the author email however i want the email field to be populated with the app_email-address. How do I go about with it. Please help.

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_author_email', 'populate_post_author_email');
function populate_post_author_email($value){

global $post;
$author_email = get_the_author_meta('email', $post->post_author);
return $author_email;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get_post_meta`

```
$app_email=  get_post_meta($post->ID,'app_email-address',true);
```

[**WP get_post_meta**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

Comment: Great thanks alot..that works perfectly. Im abit new to php, do you mind explaining what the above code means?

Comment: Its a wordpress function which gets the information from `wp_postmeta` table first parameter is the `$post->ID` each record in the `postmeta` table is link with the post_id and a key , second parameter is the `key` , it fetches the `meta_value` column value against the provided parameter for detailesd information i have provided the reference please go through it thanks

Comment: Thanks alot. Appreciate it